# How do you compile the most basic fortran program (helloworld) using gfortran an cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, gfortran

I've searched through these forums for an answer to this, but the people posing this question tend to have even a rudimentary understanding of fortran, gfortran, and cygwin.  I'm beginning a new course that focuses on Fortran, yet I cannot start on my first assignment ("hello world") given that I can't figure out how to start the process.

I'm on Windows, I have notepad++ and cygwin installed (as well as gnuplot, though I don't think that's relevant here).  Beyond that, I don't know where to start.  How do I get started here?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, step by step Cygwin Fortran(90) Hello ;-)

First in which package is the GNU Fortran compiler ?
We ask the Cygwin server with `cygcheck -p`

```
$ cygcheck -p bin/gfortran
Found 8 matches for bin/gfortran
...
gcc-fortran-10.2.0-1 - gcc-fortran: GNU Compiler Collection (Fortran)
gcc-fortran-7.4.0-1 - gcc-fortran: GNU Compiler Collection (Fortran)
gcc-fortran-9.3.0-1 - gcc-fortran: GNU Compiler Collection (Fortran)
gcc-fortran-9.3.0-2 - gcc-fortran: GNU Compiler Collection (Fortran)
```

So after you install the latest `gcc-fortran` package we have

```
$ cygcheck -c gcc-fortran
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
gcc-fortran          10.2.0-1       OK

$ cygcheck -l gcc-fortran |grep bin
/usr/bin/f95
/usr/bin/gfortran.exe
/usr/bin/x86_64-pc-cygwin-gfortran.exe
```

so the compiler you are looking for is named `gfortran`

As you have written your Fortran Hello program we can check its format
You need to save it as Unix LF format, not Windows CRLF one. You can use `d2u` to convert if needed.

```
$ file hello.f90
hello.f90: ASCII text

$ cat hello.f90
program hello
  implicit none
  write(*,*) 'Hello world!'
end program hello
```

and we can now compile and run it

```
$ gfortran hello.f90 -o hello -Wall

$ ./hello.exe
 Hello world!
```